# Como puedo lograr que haya funciones hijas dentro de una función padre

Tags: javascript, typescript

No se bien cual es el termino correcto para nombre a este tipo de funciones para eh aquí un poco de lo que llevo y quiero lograr.

```
const registrar = {
 usuario: (params) => {},
 empresa: (params) => {},
}

export default registrar;
```

Todo bien hasta aqui, puedo llamar a mi padre registrar y acceder a sus metodos

```
registrar.usuario('Test')
```

Pero me gustaria extender un poco mas mi funcionalidad, tal vez poder agregar mas metodos al metodo usuario es decir:

```
registrar.usuario('Test').disabled(true)
```

Poder seguir creando sub metodos a ese otro metodo.
Como puedo lograr esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quieres hacerte un objeto utilitario para crear otros. O sea una factoría.

Formalmente, tu objeto `registrar` no tiene métodos. Tiene llaves cuyo valor es una función. Pero podrías poner

```
 export default class Registro {
   static usuario(params) {...}
   static empresa(params) {...}
 }
```

Y serían métodos.

---

No dices si la invocación del método para registrar un usuario envía un request, persiste en una BBDD, modifica el DOM, etc etc. pero haga lo que haga, y con mayor razón si luego quieres añadir lógica a la entidad creada, *ese no es el lugar correcto*.

La factoría puede funcionar como un registro que sabe qué modelos hay en el sistema, pero no tiene por qué saber las diferencias en la lógica de dominio de cada uno a la hora de crearlos. Por ejemplo (apliquen a la regulación de su país),

- un usuario tiene número de seguridad social, la empresa no tiene tal cosa.
- una empresa tiene un VAT y un número de registro en el conservador de comercio. Un usuario no tiene tal cosa.

Lo correcto (o un poco más correcto) sería encapsular la lógica de usuarios y empresas en clases. Con el usuario, por ejemplo:

```
class Usuario {
   
   constructor(name) {
     this.name = name
     this.enabled = true
   }
   disable(flag) {
      this.enabled = !flag
   } 
}
```

En tu factoría:

```
class Registro {

   static usuario(...params) {
      return new Usuario(...params);
   }
}
```

Con eso, lo siguiente dejaría una instancia de usuario en tu variable `newUser`

```
  let newUser = Registro.usuario('Test')
```

Y de paso sería perfectamente válido desactivarlo "al vuelo" con

```
   Registro.usuario('Test').disable(true)
```

Lo malo es que eso no devuelve un usuario, pero podrías  hacer una pequeña modificación para que los métodos que modifican atributos de la instancia devuelvan la instancia misma

```
  disable(flag) {
     this.enabled = !flag
     return this
  }
```

Y con eso podrías poner:

```
 let newUser = Registro.usuario('Test')
               .disable(true)
               .disable(false)
```

Y tu variable seguiría teniendo una instancia de usuario.

Tal como ahora quisiste añadir el método que lo deshabilita, vas a querer añadir otro método más adelante. Por ejemplo,  para notificar al usuario por correo. Para que eso tenga sentido habría que instanciarlo además con un correo electŕonico

```
class Usuario {
   
   constructor(name, email) {
     this.name = name
     this.email = email
     this.enabled = true
     this.notify('Gracias por inscribirte')
   }
   disable(flag) {
      this.enabled = !flag
      return this
   } 
   notify(message) {
      enviarUnCorreo(this.email, message).then(()=> console.log('enviado!'))
      return this
   }
}
```

Y podrías hacer, por ejemplo:

```
let newUser = Registro.usuario('Test','test@mail.com')
               .disable(true)
               .notify('Te desactivamos ajajaj')
```

Te fijaste que declaré tu factoría de usuarios usando un parámetro spread?

```
static usuario(...params)
```

en vez de

```
static usuario(params)
```

Eso tenía una razón de ser, porque **después de todas las modificaciones que hicimos sobre la clase Usuario, la factoría no ha cambiado en nada**.  No necesité cambiarla por el método nuevo ni por el parámetro adicional.

Por una simple decisión de diseño, nos ahorramos modificar la factoría en el futuro cada vez que cambies la lógica de las entidades creadas.

Comment: Justo lo que estaba buscando

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr algo como lo que muestras en tu ejemplo, tendrías que usar algo como esto:

```js
const registrar = {
    usuario: (params) => { 
        return {
            disabled: (param) => { console.log(params, param)
            }
        }
    },
    empresa: (params) => {},
}
```